# Making local font work with Kendo Tree-View

Tags: css, fonts, kendo-ui, telerik, font-awesome

I am using a Kendo-Tree View and it seems to work fine for basic configuration. I am also using Font-awesome font icons with it which are also working fine. Now, I want to use an icon which does not exist on Font-awesome. Probably one of my team member may have made these  files locally and they want to use it for one of the tree-view.

I know that we do use `spriteCssClass` for font-awesome icons which work very fine. However, what do we do for non-font-awesome local icons?

Comment: It will depend entirely on the implementation of your custom icons. spriteCssClass does not just work for font-awesome, it works for the built-in kendo sprites and bootstrap glyphicons/...and any other icon library that uses CSS to define the icon/content.

Comment: what should I be exactly looking for in the implementation of this icon to make sure that spriteCssclass is supported? Because it is clearly an </i> and I was expecting it to work exactly as the font awesome icons.

Comment: If you want to use a font-based icon(like font-awesome or KendoUIGlyphs or bootstrap glyphicons) look at CSS definitions(i.e. fa fa-someicon) and you will see that it points at an actual font file(tff or eot or woff or svg) via a font-face definition and an character from that font.  Create your own font file, define the font-face in CSS, define the CSS to use the font-face and specific character. OR use a sprite implementation with an image file that contains all your icons and the corresponding CSS that returns the coordinates of the specific font...this is how kendo does its default fonts.

Comment: What part are you having trouble with? Can you use the custom fonts outside of Kendo? Can you provide a demo?